# Show an uploaded image using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, permissions

I have successfully uploaded an image in folder application/uploads codeigniter.  When I'm trying to display the image in an `<img>` tag its not showing. I've checked the path is correct and the image does exist.

Comment: please show tried code @muhammadmedhat

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: re edit you question by clicking on the edit button with some code

Comment: Update question with code samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hit that image src link on browser and check whether image is displaying or not. You can upload your images in `assets` folder. Call your image by using url `https://yoururl.com/assets/imgfolder/img.jpg` . It should display. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the tag you are using with the path. If you believe the path is correct, can you type this path straight into your browser and see the image displayed? You can do a 'view source' to get the path if you are using Codeigniter base_url or similar.

(sorry to post this as an answer but my rep isn't high enough to allow commenting)